# Exclude ASP.NET - Requisition messages from log

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging

so I've been coding a WebAPI and now I want it to log some specific information throughout the run, but for some reason it's logging these messages. [APPLICATION STARTED!!!] was my implementation, but everything below it wasn't and I don't want it to be in my log file.

this is how my appsettings looks like:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "None",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None",
      "Microsoft.AspNet": "None"
    }
  },
```

this is where I'm calling services.AddLogging

```
services.AddLogging(configure =>
            {
                this.ConfigureLogger();
                Log.Information("[APPLICATION STARTED!!!]");
                configure.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                configure.AddSerilog();
            });
```

ConfigureLogger:

```
public void ConfigureLogger()
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
            string day = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM");
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  .WriteTo.Console()
                  .WriteTo.File($@"C:\apiCEFJUD\api\Logs\LogsRoboCEFJud_Dia{day}\LogsRoboCEFJud{timestamp}.txt")
                  .CreateLogger();
        }
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .SuppressStatusMessages(true)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
```

Log message:

```
[15:57:18 INF] [APPLICATION STARTED!!!]
[15:57:19 INF] User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\ATIVA-DANIEL TI\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[15:57:20 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:6009/index.html
[15:57:20 INF] Request finished in 69.5148ms 200 text/html;charset=utf-8
[15:57:20 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:6009/swagger/v0/swagger.json
[15:57:20 INF] Request finished in 106.0999ms 200 application/json;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Please use code snippets and not screenshots to show code.

Comment: @Achtung I'm sorry, just fixed it!